# Nautilus crashes all desktop folders gone

Tags: nautilus, directory, crash

After copying a lot of jpgs from folder A to folder B
the desktop-image and all folders are no longer visible.
After clicking any folder-sign on the panel one folder shortly opens 
and after 3sec crashes.
After all I purged nautilus, reinstalled it, resetted the ownership
of all config-files in the home directory nothing improved
Folders are gone.
Login as a different user or starting gksu nautilus in the terminal
all works fine.
So what can I do to reactivate the home-users nautilus?
Thank you for any help
Distrib ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: what does ls say in the terminal?
are there folders according to ls?

Comment: @Peter I can see the folders in the terminal and in Nautilus of a different user

Comment: what config files are you referring to? usually in situations like this, settings/config file are damaged. Changing permissions does not help, deleting them often does. I would try to temporarily rename nautilus settings/config files in  ~/.config/nautilus` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes more time to research a problem then to solve it.  I've got 2 dirty tricks up my sleeve to solve it *without knowing where the problem came from*. If you *ever* have this problem again, we can still research it then.

If you disagree with this approach, leave a comment below the answer.

**Trick 1**: It doesn't appear in the guest session, right? So create an additional user, copy (and then delete.  do *not move*) all your files from the "crashed user" to the new user and delete the "crashed user"

**Trick 2**: Nautilus is causing the problem, right? Install [Nemo File Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-nemo-220-with-unity-patches-in.html). It's how Nautilus used to be a few years ago, before Nautilus suffered from the "simple is better" syndrome... :-( Lots of options, keeps the views you define, built-in terminal, ... Overall a better file manager.